# Removing instances of a string from a JSON file and then parsing it

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, fs

I have a JSON file with a lot of content and I load it with the fs Node.js module. But when I look in the JSON file I noticed there is a string of characters attached to many of the field names that make it impossible to target in JS. It looks something like this:

```
"bk:ParentField": {
       "bk:Field": "Value",
       "bk:Field2": "Value2"
}
```

I want to remove the `bk:` part because I am unable to target the objects with them in it. My code looks like this :

```
 var contents = fs.readFileSync("results.json");
 var jsonContent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(contents).replace(/bk:/g, '' ));
```

The problem that whenever I try to target an item after running the code above, I get an error saying an undefined or if I do something like `jsonContent['bk:ParentField']` I still get an undefined error. 
Any ideas on why this would happen? Or is there a workaround to targeting the objects with the 'bk:'?

Comment: You know you can just do `obj['bk:ParentField']` to access those keys

Comment: Yes, but I've been getting an error when I try doing it because of the colon within.

Comment: It works just fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/g4m4g2hv/1/

Comment: Tried your code and it seems to be working. How do you access the fields?

Comment: I have tried the way @adeneo pointed out but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) returns a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) if an encoding is not provided and `JSON.stringify` takes an Object not a string or buffer.

Just call `toString()` on the `contents` buffer before using `replace()` and then use `JSON.parse` to create a JavaScript Object:

```
fs = require('fs');

var contents = fs.readFileSync("test.json");
var data = JSON.parse(contents.toString().replace(/bk:/g, ''));
```

Or provide an encoding:

```
fs = require('fs');

var contents = fs.readFileSync("test.json", "utf-8");
var data = JSON.parse(contents.replace(/bk:/g, ''));
```

Both methods yield the expected result and allow properties to accessed with the `.` operator:

```
console.log(data.ParentField.Field);
```

The `replace` is not strictly required if you don't mind accessing properties like so:

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("test.json", "utf-8"));
console.log(data["bk:ParentField"]["bk:Field"])
```

Comment: This worked great! I am unsure why `stringify` or something like this `obj['bk:ParentField']` didn't work though.

Comment: @VicDid `stringify` takes an object, I have update my answer, hopefully this is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is not the `:` in the object keys, but the fact that there are no enclosing `{}` in your JSON string, which makes it invalid. See this example:

```js
var parsed = JSON.parse(`{
  "bk:ParentField": {
    "bk:Field": "Value",
    "bk:Field2": "Value2"
  }
}`)
console.log(parsed['bk:ParentField'])
```

Comment: The JSON in the file is enclosed with the bracket. The problem was the colon. Some errors even specifically pointed out the colon.

Comment: I think i misinterpreted your question - it might be helpful if you add a concrete error to your question.